# Haskell add to list in list

Tags: haskell

i have the following code

```
groupEq :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupEq list = foldl (\acc x -> if (isType acc x) then ((last acc) ++ [x]) else acc++[[x]]) [] list

isType :: Eq a => [[a]] -> a -> Bool
isType list item 
    | (length list) == 0 = False
    | head (last list) == item = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Now, i am having difficulties understanding why it would not compile.
The problem is with the `((last acc) ++ [x])` part of it. I understand it as it takes the last element of accumulator, which would be [[a]] at this point and tries to add an element to it.

The idea what i want to achieve is this:
`-- groupEq [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,1,1] ==> [[1], [2,2], [3,3,3], [4], [1,1]]`

Full error is

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘[a]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for groupEq :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
          at exam_revisited.hs:3:12
    Expected type: [[[a]]]
      Actual type: [[a]]
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: a (bound at exam_revisited.hs:4:28)
      acc :: [[a]] (bound at exam_revisited.hs:4:24)
      list :: [a] (bound at exam_revisited.hs:4:9)
      groupEq :: [a] -> [[a]] (bound at exam_revisited.hs:4:1)
    In the first argument of ‘last’, namely ‘acc’
    In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘(last acc)’
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Post the full error.

Comment: @chi Added error to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groupEq is declared to return `[[a]]`, but `((last acc) ++ [x])` is of type `[a]`.
A quick and dirty solution is to change this expression into
`init acc ++ [last acc ++ [x]]`.

Comment: @bipill Yes you are right indeed. But i wonder why setting the accumulator to [[]] at start wouldn't help. Wouldn't then be `((last acc) ++ [x])` type of `[[a]]` ?

Comment: Definitely not. `last [[]]` is `[]` and it has type `[a]`.